# Grails - Spring Security Plugin issue

Tags: grails, gradle, spring-security

I am trying to add `grails spring security plugin` to a project but getting this error.

```
Error:Could not find spring-security-core.zip (org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.zip
```

My `build.gradle` file looks like this

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1")
}
```

Grails version is `3.1.9` and gradle version is `3.3`.

Comment: Can you write the url from which maven is getting the dependencies?

Comment: @JuanParra https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.zip

Why it is finding .zip? it should find .jar which is there

Comment: try changing it for https://repo.grails.org/grails/core in your build.gradle file in   `repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }` blocks